# Spring-WebSocket y ReactTypescript - Full authentication is required to access this resource

Tags: typescript, spring, websocket

Es mi primera vez utilizando Spring WebSocket con React Typescript y estoy intentando implementarlo en una aplicación ya creada.

Esta es la configuración que he añadido a mi aplicación

*Config:*

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 99)
public class WebSocketMessageConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(final StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/api/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(final MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }

}
```

*Security config:*

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(final MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
        messages.simpDestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated().anyMessage().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

*Controller:*

```
@Controller
public class GrettingWSController {

    @MessageMapping("/api/ws")
    @SendTo("/topic")
    public String handle(final String greeting) {
        return "[" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ": " + greeting;
    }
}
```

Y aquí esta el código que utilizo desde el cliente (React Typescript):

```
let sockJS = this.socketFactory();
sockJS.onopen = function () {
           console.log('Client connection opened');
       };

sockJS.onerror = function (event: any) {
           console.log('Client error: ' + event);
       };

sockJS.onclose = function (event: any) {
           console.log('Client connection closed: ' + event.code);
       };

[...]

private socketFactory() {
        return new SockJS('https://localhost:8443/api/ws');
    }
```

Cuando arranco el cliente y se intenta conectar obtengo este error en la consola de Spring:

```
Full authentication is required to access this resource org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException: Full authentication is required to access this resource
 org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleSpringSecurityException(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:177)
 org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:133)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 com.caixabank.koa.common.authentication.jwt.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
 org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
 org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
 org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
 org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
 org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
 org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
 org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
 org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
 org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
 org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
 org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
 org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Utilizo Spring 4.3.14 y React 16.8.6.

En la aplicación ya existente tengo configurado Spring Security y utiliza jwttoken.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

Gracias! :)

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente añadí

```
.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/ws/*").permitAll()
```

en la configuración de Spring-Security y ya me puedo conectar correctamente.

Comment: Lo que hiciste es quitar la seguridad del Socket ahora cualquier programa se puede conectar sin autenticación, si debes de utilizar jwttoken debes de ver el servicio de autenticación de tu back-end y enviar las credenciales para que te retorne el token.